# why string.find("</a>") cant find "</a>"?

Tags: html, c++, string, find

My program works entirely good except it doesn't find for `</a>`.
It can find everything e.g. it can find `</b>`, `</i>`, `</head>` etc but not `</a>` for some reason?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    string HTML_text;
    getline(cin, HTML_text, '\t');
    cout << endl << "Printing test!";

    // replacing hyperlink
    string sub_string;
    int index_begin = HTML_text.find("<a href=") + 8;
    string helper = HTML_text.substr(index_begin, HTML_text.size());
    int index_end = helper.find(">");
    helper.clear();
    sub_string = HTML_text.substr(index_begin, index_end);
    //substring is made

    index_begin = HTML_text.find(">", index_begin) + 1;
    index_end = HTML_text.find("</a>");       //HERE IS THE PROBLEM
    helper = HTML_text.substr(index_begin, index_end);
    cout << "\n\nPrinting helper!\n";
    cout << helper << endl << endl;

    HTML_text.erase(index_begin, index_end);

    HTML_text.insert(index_begin, sub_string);

    cout << endl << "Printing results!";
    cout << endl << endl << HTML_text << endl << endl;
}
```

The HTML.text that I am using for example is this:

```
<html>
<head>
text to be deleted
</head>
<body>
Hi there!
<b>some bold text</b>
<i>italic</i>
<a href=www.abc.com>link text</a>
</body>
</html>      //tab and then enter
```

Comment: Hi! You can use ` quotes (altgr+7 on windows) to add inline code, that way you can write html tags :)

Comment: @dingo_d I was doing some testing, and it still have some problems, it doesnt exactly set the integer index_end at the position where "< / a >"  is, I feel like it sets it somewhere in the middle between "<a>" and "< / a >".

Comment: Well `<a>` and other are html tags, so the site will try to render it (a is anchor, i is icon, b is bold etc).

Comment: Oh and I was referring to the stackoverflow, how to write tags without using <./a> (dots) in it. In your code you should use " or ' quotes, not `.

Comment: I am doing it in c++ i dont think it has something to do with html :S

Comment: Seems to work for me: http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/225b75e95de243cb , or you should prepare _minimal_ example and provide what you get and what expect.

Comment: @Petr its far from good, look at the last line of the output, it removes the rest of the program (in this case "</'body>") just to print the hyperlink

Comment: Then please provide the **minimal** example to reproduce the problem, **and** the expected output. Nobody can guess what exactly are **you** expecting from the program.

Comment: ...note that minimal means that you'd better remove all non-relevant parts of the code. Try experiment around and remove processing of other tags, so that it will be easier to find your problem.

Comment: Read the documentation for `substr` again and pay particular attention to the meaning of its second parameter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is not where you assumed it is: `index_end = HTML_text.find("</a>");` works correctly and finds the position in the string where `</a>` is contained: you can see easily in a debugger if you watch the value `index_end`. In case `</a>` wouldn't be found, `index_end` would be equal to [std::string::npos](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/npos/)), but it's 123 while `index_begin` is 114.

Let's take a look at the documentation for [std::string.erase()](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/erase/)

```
string& erase (size_t pos = 0, size_t len = npos);
```

The signature of the erase method has two parameters, the position and the **length** while your code assumed, that the second parameter would be the end position (the same is also true, for [std::string.substr()](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/substr/)).

That's not a big problem and can be fixed easily, as we can calculate the length simply by

```
length = end_position - start_position;
```

So your fixed code would be:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
  string HTML_text;
  getline(cin, HTML_text, '\t');
  cout << endl << "Printing test!";

  // replacing hyperlink
  string sub_string;
  int index_begin = HTML_text.find("<a href=") + 8;
  string helper = HTML_text.substr(index_begin);
  int index_end = helper.find(">");
  helper.clear();
  sub_string = HTML_text.substr(index_begin, index_end);
  //substring is made

  index_begin = HTML_text.find(">", index_begin) + 1;
  index_end = HTML_text.find("</a>");
  helper = HTML_text.substr(index_begin, index_end - index_begin);
  cout << "\n\nPrinting helper!\n";
  cout << helper << endl << endl;

  HTML_text.erase(index_begin, index_end - index_begin);

  HTML_text.insert(index_begin, sub_string);

  cout << endl << "Printing results!";
  cout << endl << endl << HTML_text << endl << endl;
}
```

Which outputs, as you would expect:

```
Printing test!

Printing helper!
link text


Printing results!

<html>
<head>
text to be deleted
</head>
<body>
Hi there!
<b>some bold text</b>
<i>italic</i>
<a href=www.abc.com>www.abc.com</a>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thank you for taking your time to clear me the things.